# Horizontal scroll view scrolls but only partially and bounces back to original position

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I've got a horizontal scroll view with content as follows:

[image]

When I run it scrolls horizontally partially - I can scroll until about half of the red view is visible but then it bounces back.
How can I get it so that it can scroll all the way so all the red view is visible and then stays there?

I have this in the view controller, but it makes no difference if there or not.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    print("Content view bounds: \(contentView.bounds)")
    scrollView.layoutIfNeeded()
    scrollView.contentSize = contentView.bounds.size
}
```

In the screenshot of the storyboard there is no trailing edge constraint for the red view, however if I add one between the red view and the content view then when I run on the device it stops scrolling and looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need to be explicitly setting the `.contentSize` to begin with -- you can let auto-layout handle it all for you.

First, delete your `Content View.width = width` constraint:

[image]

Having that constraint told auto-layout to make your `contentView` ***only as wide as*** the scroll view, so you wouldn't get any horizontal scrolling. By explicitly setting the `.contentSize` you got some scrolling, but as you found it didn't give you what you wanted.

After deleting that constraint, add a 20-pt trailing constraint from `Red View` to the trailing edge of the content view:

[image]

Now, you have a complete chain of horizontal constraints...

```
- Blue View.leading = leading + 20
- Blue View Width
- Red View.leading = Blue View.trailing + 40
- Red View Width
- trailing = Red View.trailing + 20
```

This satisfies auto-layout and properly defines the width of `Content View`... and since `Content View` is constrained to leading and trailing of your Scroll View, you get correct horizontal scrolling.

No need for any code.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by adding the following:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 750,height: 812)
}
```

But why does the above work but not the following?

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    print("Content view bounds: \(contentView.bounds)")
    scrollView.layoutIfNeeded()
    scrollView.contentSize = contentView.bounds.size
}
```

At runtime contentView.bounds is (0.0, 0.0, 750.0, 812.0)